# How to ensure a class can only be instantiated by Spring?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

I am re-factoring a legacy Java application to use Spring.

This involves declaring the application classes as Spring beans and then replacing all occurrences of `new` with `context.getBean` OR with `DI`.

I'm re-writing application logic in way that some classes become singletons. However since they are being instantiated using new in other locations, multiple copies would exist which would mess up the business logic.
I'd like to ensure that application explicitly fails whenever it tries to instantiate an object by itself, instead of running and misbehaving in unpredictable ways. (I'm not sure that the re-factoring has covered 100% of the application there still might be new lurked up in some corner)

What is the best way of ensuring that a class can only be instantiated by Spring container?
(I'm hoping to avoid writing a factory for each class)

Comment: You classes are singletons?

Comment: In scenario "application explicitly fails whenever it tries to instantiate an object by itself, instead of running and misbehaving in unpredictable ways" it is not possible .Though spring DI container manages yours objects life cycle but within urs system to track more than two instance of  class is not possible.When the object is created outside the scope of spring DI You have to manage it manually .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As from your question

> In this particular scenario only one copy of an object should exist which is fetched from the context, multiple copies would mess up the business logic.

you can create classic singleton and use `getInstance()` method as factory method in bean definition in spring's xml file:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="MyClass" factory-method="getInstance"/>
```

Make your constructor private, and than no one can call it. Additionally you will see errors in compile time, if some parts of old code uses `new` to instantiate your class.